# Casbin: Retrieve all objects for subject with particular action. RBAC use case

Tags: casbin

I need to implement custom RBAC support for my product and I stumbled upon casbin/jcasbin that looks promising.

I am checking java API and I do not seem to find a way to fetch all objects of a particular type that a user has access to.

Say, I am implementing an API (not necessarily a REST-based) that is supposed to return a list of all entities the user has `read` access to.

What jcasbin API call would that be?

I am looking into `Enforcer` interface and it seems to check whether a user (subject) can do a particular action on the given object.

How do I list all the objects for a user with the given action?

I think RBAC with resource roles is what I want, my `model.conf`:

```
[request_definition]
r = sub, obj, act

[policy_definition]
p = sub, obj, act

[role_definition]
g = _, _
g2 = _, _

[policy_effect]
e = some(where (p.eft == allow))

[matchers]
m = g(r.sub, p.sub) && g2(r.obj, p.obj) && r.act == p.act


p, role:viewer, context, read
g, alice, role:viewer
g2, c1, context
g2, c2, context
```

Here, `viewer` role grants `read` permission to the entity type `context`.
`alice` is assigned `viewer` role.
`c1` and `c2` objects are of type `context`.
Now, I want to `read` all `contexts` for the user `alice`.

P.S.: I am not sure if SO is the right venue for these types of questions.

Comment: See my reply here: https://github.com/casbin/jcasbin/issues/185#issuecomment-831633292

Comment: Yang Lou: I didn't see an answer I understood in that thread.

for example: I want to query to find out, for which set of objects, can Alice do the action "read"?

..or better still, which objects containing the regex /^book.*$/

Answer (score 0):

Use the new added `batchEnforce()` API: https://github.com/casbin/jcasbin/issues/187